# Permutahedron edge

Tags: permutations, polytopes

Let's suppose we have the permutahedron (1,2,3,4) and all the possible  permutations . I try to find an edge of this polytope . I try to find a hyperplane a1*x1+a2*x2+a3*x3+a4*x4 = b,  such that  (1,3,2,4) and (1,4,2,3) passing through the hyperplane  i.e 
a1*(1) + a2*(3) + a3*(2) + a4*(4) = b
a1*(1) + a2*(4) + a3*(2) + a4*(3) = b
But we want for all the other permutations to be a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3*x3 + a4*x4 > b or a1*x1 + a2*x2 + a3*x3 + a4*x4 < b and of course not for some permutations < b and for other >b . 
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

To define an edge in four dimensions requires three intersecting hyperplanes. One hyperplane is the one in which the entire permutahedron lives:

$$
a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=10\;.
$$

To find the other two, look at [this Wikipedia illustration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron#/media/File:Symmetric_group_4;_permutohedron_3D;_permutations_and_inversion_vectors.svg). The edge between $1324$ and $1423$ (coloured in red) is the intersection of the faces that $1324$ and $1423$ form with $2413$ and $2314$ (a square) and with $1432$, $1342$, $1243$ and $1234$ (a regular hexagon). You could use generalized cross products to find vectors that are normal to these faces, but it's also not too difficult to guess hyperplanes that define them (together with the above hyperplane for the entire permutahedron), for instance,

$$
a_1-a_2+a_3-a_4=-4
$$

for the square and

$$
a_1=1
$$

for the regular hexagon.

Comment: ok i agree but you helped by the picture from the wikipedia link .. you know the adjacent facet and you take the intersect .. but without the picture what we can do let suppose for permutahedron of (1 ,2 ,3, 4, 5) how can we find an edge

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis: You should specify what exactly you mean by "finding an edge". An edge can also be described by a position vector and a direction vector. Do you want to specify it by $4$ hyperplanes?

Comment: your way to find an edge is to take adjacent facets which intersection is the looking edge ...but you use as a fact the image of wiki where you can see the adjacent facets ..... how can we generalize your thought for example the permutahedron (1,2,3,4,5,6) or higher dimension.